# Trying to replicate glowing circle effect

Tags: android, android-canvas, draw, glow

I am trying to replicate the glowing effect of the circles in this game: http://hakim.se/experiments/html5/coil/

Currently I can draw a circle with:

```
canvas.drawCircle(Parameters);
```

However I have no idea how to make the circles emit that soft glowing effect.

So far it seems like I need to use a paint's shadow layer but that is not working.

Here is what I currently have:

```
blue = new Paint(); //This is in my view's constructor.
blue.setARGB(255, 51, 153, 255);
blue.setShadowLayer(100,0,0, Color.BLUE);
```

Then I have this in the onDraw method:

```
canvas.drawCircle(300,300,20,blue);
```

However I do not see any glow effect.

How can I achieve/mimic the glowing effect of those circles either by using shadow layers or something else?

Comment: I imagine you could just draw another larger circle overtop using an alpha paint and then animate the alpha or if you don't want it going beyond the darker circle then just animating the alpha or showing it/removing it in one quick move. Probably several other ways as well.

Why you don't see any glowing effect could be other problems with your code then the code you show - you need to be doing more than that unless you only intend to make the entire circle itself change not similar to what you linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this line of code where you've initialized the paint.

```
setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, blue);
```

Screen-shot:

[image: glowing circle]

Comment: While this has worked the glow is very faint and my program has become very laggy (at least on the emulator).

Comment: @Roymunson In real devices it works fine and smoothly.

Comment: @Roymunson If you'd want to create a game, you'd better off to use a game engine.

Comment: @Roymunson Pass a brighter color to `setShadowLayer`.

Comment: How do I pass a brighter color to "setShadowLayer" ? The parameter has to be  an int, such as Color.BLUE, I can't pass a paint object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101124/discussion-between-roymunson-and-hi-im-frogatto).